# In Tomcat, java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, jar, jaxb

I am trying to load my webapp into Tomcat. It seems to be complaining that it has an older version of a JAR than my application. Should I remove that older JAR, use a newer version of Java, edit the bootstrap classloader (how?) or what?

> Message: JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI (from jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%205.5/webapps/SkillsDB/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class) needs 2.2 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap classloader. (See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/guide/standards/)
>
> Caused by: Executing action [getDocx] of controller [FormattedDocumentController] caused exception: `java.lang.LinkageError`: JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI (from jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%205.5/webapps/SkillsDB/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class) needs 2.2 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap classloader. (See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/guide/standards/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your JAXB 2.2 JARs in

```
%JAVA_HOME%\lib\endorsed
```

It should work.

If your Java is installed in

```
C:\Program Files\Java
```

then you should put JAXB 2.2 JARs in:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\lib\endorsed
```

directory.

Comment: This would have to be done on every system he's planning on running his webapp on.  There's got to be a less intrusive way than modifying the Java installation.  I'll see what I can find.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't worked for me (may be because I was using Netbeans 6.9). So I figured out a similar solution in which I created the endorsed folder within CATALINA_HOME (tomcat installation directory) and put my jaxb-api2.2.jar there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why, but I solved it in following way.

I realized Tomcat was using a **JVM** (jre1.6.0_03) **that was not the default one** (jre1.6.0_26, in folder *C:\Program Files\Java\jre6*).

So I stopped Tomcat, launched the program "Configure Tomcat", in "Java" tabsheet chose "Use default" and then started again Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Put your JAXB 2.2 JARs in  folder, you need first find out where this folder is using this:

System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.endorsed.dirs"));

Mine was d:\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed