# LinkageError when creating web service (Tomcat, CXF and Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

I want to create a simple web service in Eclipse (Helios J2EE), using Apache CXF 2.3.2 and Tomcat 7. 
However, when I use the 'New web service' wizard, I get the following error at WSDL creation:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI (from jar:file:/C:/Users/me/apache-cxf-2.3.2/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.1.1.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class) needs 2.2 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap classloader. (See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/guide/standards/)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<clinit>(ModelBuilder.java:173)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:456)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:210)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:368)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createContext(JAXBDataBinding.java:557)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:497)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:324)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:87)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:445)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:508)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:245)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractServiceFactory.createService(AbstractServiceFactory.java:78)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.process(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:101)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.processWSDL(JavaToWSContainer.java:110)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.execute(JavaToWSContainer.java:75)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:58)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:40)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.run(JavaToWS.java:77)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.main(JavaToWS.java:45)
```

I found [some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4159043/505893) suggesting to copy *jaxb-api-2.2.1.jar* in `%JAVA_HOME%/lib/endorsed`, but that doesn't work for me...

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: [Here][1] is what you can do to resolve your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159028/force-tomcat-to-use-my-jar

Comment: Take a look also to [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8832530/505893).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, some information may help you solve this problem by your own:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI (from jar:file:/C:/Users/me/apache-cxf-2.3.2/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.1.1.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class) needs 2.2 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap classloader. (See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/guide/standards/)
```

1. Do you know what is the **bootstrap classloader**? Its a "super" class loader. If you put a JAR in this classloader you can overwrite even `java.lang.*` classes. It's the first class loader in any Java application. It's a powerfull thing.
2. Let's take a look in your message:

   > JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI ([...]) needs 2.2 API [...].

   You just need to replace the version of your JAXB API, right? So, check what is on your bootstrap class loader (try print all `JAVA_*` variables and Java start line to find your bootstrap) and find what is wrong. Probably some JAR has the old version of JAXB and need to be replaced. Only that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually managed to solve the issue by providing the -Djava.endorsed.dirs option in the configuration of the JRE used by my project (adding the lib/endorsed folder from the CXF directory). Thanks again