# Building a project gave me java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader

Tags: java, jaxb, classloader, endorsed

While building project I am getting the following error:

> `java.lang.LinkageError`: JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI (from jar:file:/C:/Documents and Settings/ind/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.4-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class) needs 2.2 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap classloader. (See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/guide/standards/)

Please reply asp.

Comment: Take a look also to [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8832530/505893).

Answer (score 1):

A JAXB 2.1 implementation is included with Java SE 6, and an implementation of JAXB 2.2 is included in Java SE 7.  Unless you have a requirement to do so, I would recommend using a JAXB implementation that conforms with the JAXB APIs included in the version of Java you are using.

Comment: Thanks for reply Blaise. by keeping the jaxb.jar in to jdk/lib i have solved this problem.