# java.lang.linkage error? in opencms

Tags: java, apache, jaxb, opencms

i AM deploying opencms.war in apache tomcat 6.0.35 i got an error

```
    Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.0 API is being loaded from the bootstrap
    classloader, but this RI (from jar:file:/C:/software/tomcat6/webapps/messaging/
    WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.11.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class)
    needs 2.1 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the
    bootstrap classloader. 
    (See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/standards/)
```

i am using jdk1.7.0 and jre1.7.0

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159028/in-tomcat-java-lang-linkageerror-jaxb-2-1-api-is-being-loaded-from-the-bootstr

Comment: java is installed at c:/program files/java/jdk1.7.0 and c:/program files/java/jre1.7.0

Comment: Did you put your JAXB jars into the correct folder? %JAVA_HOME%\lib\endorsed

Comment: Environment variables are: path c:/program files/java/jdk1.7.0/bin                                                       and JAVA_HOME c:/program files/java/jdk1.7.0

Comment: i have put jaxb-api-2.1.jar in c:/program files/java/jdk1.7.0/lib/endorsed folder is it correct?

Comment: It should be. Try once more and report us

Comment: plz tell me how to set JAVA_HOME, CATALINA_PATH in environment variables java is installed at c:/program files/java/jdk1.7.0

Comment: These two answers shows how to set JAVA_HOME, CATALINA_PATH. Check them. If that does not help you, I do not have any idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579661/how-to-set-catalina-home-variable-in-windows-7

Comment: i have done all the things but the problem persists what can i do?